# Reuse raspberry pi 3 spi after installing touchscreen driver

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I installed a 5 inch raspberry pi touch screen driver and it work well. Now I need to disable the screen and use the spi in an RFID code.
I need a method to disable the screen and clear the gpio pins.

I tried to use 
disable_touchscreen=1 
but nothing happens.

Then I tried 
Xinput and disable the screen, the touch stopped but the pins didn't cleared .

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions.  Specifcally, you need to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: After reinstalling a new raspberrian image that came with a pre added touch screen driver, which solved the problem partially. Now all the GPIO pins work under any condition wether the screen is added or not. However I am still having problem with the spi to reuse it.